# How to delete equals?

Tags: notebooks

I have a equals symbol that Mathematica won't let me delete. I have a screenshot of the equals symbol in Mathematica. How do I delete the first orange equals symbol in Mathematica? I have tried the delete key and Mathematica won't let me delete the orange equals symbol?

[image]

Comment: You ended up creating a different styled cell than the one you want. Just delete the entire cell itself and make a new `"Input"` or `"Text"` cell via the standard shortcuts. The thing that I'm sure tripped you up is that this new cell is created if you press `=` in an empty `Input` cell or between cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to hit <kbd>Backspace</kbd> (<kbd>Delete</kbd> on MacOS) or <kbd>=</kbd> twice. If these don't work, report what:

```
CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "WolframAlphaShort", StyleKeyMapping}]
```

> {"=" -> "WolframAlphaLong", "Backspace" -> "Input"}

evaluates to on your computer.

Comment: Pressing equals button twice on keyboard works great. Thank you.